# How to get .env from root project into React client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sh, dotenv

I'm trying to do something that should be REALLY simple but it's proving exceedingly difficult. I've burned 4 hrs on this today.  I have a nodeJS project with server and client parts. I'm using concurrently to launch them both.  I want to use the same .env for both server and client. Should be simple, right? Apparently not.  The problem is that when I try to use dotenv in my React client, it never finds the .env no matter what I do, and the reason is that __dirname (and process.cwd()) always point to the root directory (i.e. /).  I need it to be a relative path, or at least I need to pass somehow the explicit path to my react app.
I've even tried running the client directly by calling 'npm start' from my client directory - the process.cws() still defaults to the root partition and not my project directory.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
+project_root
  - .env
  - index.js
  - package.json (for the server side) 
  + client
       - package.json (for client)
       + src 
          - App.js (this is where I'm trying to access .env)
```

My package.json for the server has the following in the scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "start-watch": "nodemon index.js",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-watch\" \"cd client && npm start\""
      }
```

On the client side I have

```
 "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",         
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

I normally start all of this from the project root by calling 'npm run dev'. However, I thought to try and build a run script for it, and from my run script pass in environment variables of the form REACT_APP_
The above works, but in the absence of being able to actually get REACT to set itself to be in a directory other than root, I still cannot get React to read the project .env.
What I've been trying next is to have my run script output all the contents of .env as REACT environment variables. I so far haven't got it to work, here is the run script I tried:

```
!/bin/sh
export REACT_APP_CURR_DIR=`pwd`
grep -v '^#' .env | while read line
do 
   echo exporting line $line
   VARNAME=REACT_APP_`echo $line | sed -E 's/(.*)=.*/\1/'`  
   VALUE=`echo $line | sed -E 's/(.*)=(.*)/\2/'`
   echo $VARNAME

   `export ${VARNAME}=${VALUE}` 

done
npm run dev
```

When I do this, it barfs on some of the variables, but none of them make it into process.env within my react client.

Am I missing something very basic here?  I feel like I've gone to extreme lengths just to have server and client use the same .env file so I'm not duplicating parameters everywhere. Even if I put a .env file in my client, the fact that even executing npm start is not giving the React app the right directory is problematic.

I can't believe no one has come into this before.

Comment: Be careful of what you are actually passing to the actual built/served react app. Avoid injecting any kind of secret api keys or similar as they will be exposed. One question I’d ask is do you really need all the server environment variables passed to the front end. If express is serving be front end react application, you have a secure proxy for interacting with databases, apis, and similar and therefore can keep some amount of environment variables only on the server. This is actually why create react app variables are prefixed to avoid leaking secure values.

Comment: I actually did find a better way.  The server .env had an API key that I need to call a geolocation service.  I instead had react call *my* API and build an API stub to call the geolocation service and return the results to React.  That bypassed my need (for now) to read .env params from React.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what you usually do to avoid exposing api secret keys and avoid cors issues